# Azure functions pulse - no data

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I recently created my first Azure Function, which runs fine - I've had ~16,000 requests in the last hour which I can see under the monitor tab. However the pulse telemetry screen shows nothing - just empty graphs as if no functions are being run. I've done the whole opening new tabs, different browsers, reboot thing and no change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you look at the console / network requests in browser developer tools? You may see some failed requests / errors that help explain the issue.

Comment: Are you using a corporate login or a personal MSA? I have the same issue and also 200 OK's, but the issue only exists when I'm on my corporate login. I've created an issue here: https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/914

Comment: Yes its a corp login. I'll give it a go on my personal and see if I have the same

Answer (score 1):

We identified the root cause of the problem and fixed this. 
The fix has been deployed to production. Please try again.

Comment: Hi, and thanks Shekhar, but this hasn't fixed my issue. I actually created another functions app after seeing your answer and I'm getting exactly the same issue there - in chrome I can see lots of requests being made by angular, all coming back with 200s. The graphs are there but with no data in them

Comment: mind sharing your function name and container site name on my email? Some things you can try:
- do CTRL+F5 on the browser for AAD refresh and reopen "Live Stream"

Comment: Thanks a lot - I couldn't find your email so I've messaged you through LI